# How to create a product only menu in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I'm building a site that is starting only with only 2 products, so a category menu is not appropriate and I'm attempting to create a product only menu.

I'm using a commercial theme and it automagically generates a category menu in header.tpl

I need to create a product menu but not being a php coder it gets tricky, so far I have:

```
<ul id="topnav">
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: It is because of undefined variables, but how do I define the $products and $products variables?

Comment: make sure your $products contains a bunch of data in array or object form before running through foreach conditions. By the way you may print_r and exit to check the output first.

Comment: thanks Eric, I gave that a go but it seems I need to define a variable to make it work which brings me back to where I started ;)

Comment: If you are not a programmer I suggest you to find someone to do that for you. it's not a hard thing to do, but at the same time it's not something that someone can tell you what to do here :)

Comment: ok no worries, good point Tohid, i will do that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer thanks to a kind member of the OpenCart forum.

Just put this code where you need it:

```
<?php
    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $products_1 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data = array());                                   
    if ($products_1) {$output = '<ul id="topnav">';}                                               
    foreach ($products_1 as $product_1) {                                                         
       $output .= '<li>';                                                                                                         
       $unrewritten  = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_1['product_id']);                        
       $output .= '<a href="'.($unrewritten).'">' . $product_1['model'] . '</a>';                        
    }
    if ($products_1) {$output .= '</ul>';}                                             
    echo $output;                                                          
    ?>
```

[Credit goes to the forum member here.](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=82027&p=337912#p337912)

Answer (score 2):

Opencart uses the Model-View-Controller framework (MVC) where the Controller talks to the Model to retrieve data, prepares the data and then passes it to the View (the .tpl files in Opencart) which then displays it appropriately.

In your case the header.tpl doesn't have the data for $products array because it has not been prepared in the header.php controller yet. So in the index() function of the header controller (catalog/controller/header.php) let's get all the data from our models, prepare it how we want and then pass it to the view:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');   //
$this->load->model('catalog/product');    //Load our models so the controller can get data
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);  //get all top level categories
$all_products = array();
foreach ($categories as $category)  //go through each category and get all the products for each category
{
$category_products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductsforCategoryId($category['category_id']); //returns product IDs for category
foreach ($category_products as $category_product)
{
    $product_data = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($category_product);   //fetch product data for this product then add it to our array of all products
    $all_products[] = array(
        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_data['product_id']),
        'name'        => $product_data['name']
    );
}
}
$this->data['products'] = $all_products;  //Now pass our product array data to the view, in the view this will be the $products array
```

This is assuming all your products belong to only top level categories and not any subcategories. If you do create subcategories of the top level categories in the future you will need to loop through those subcategories and get the products for each one.

Comment: Wow thanks Bhavik! I see what you mean, I'm familiar with the MVC framework - from a frontend developers point of view ;)

I see this is way beyond my skill set, I'll have to hire someone to do it. Also I guess this needs to be done using vqmod to avoid having to edit any core files and then not being able to upgrade.

Thanks again Bhavik! :)

Comment: If you just copy paste that code into the header controller (somewhere in the index() function) and add the code you gave in your question in your view (header.tpl) it should work! Also its not necessary to use vqmod, when you start developing in opencart away from the default you should duplicate the default theme in to your own one and then just copy/paste this folder back in to the theme folder after you upgrade

Comment: Thanks Bhavik, I did give it a go but I got:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelCatalogProduct::getProductsforCategoryId() in ***/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 153

which is: 
$category_products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductsforCategoryId($category['category_id']); //returns product IDs for category

The header.php file is not part of the template so surely that means it is a core mod?